# Declaring a winner in tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe program.  So far I have the 3x3 grid, and I'm able to drag and drop X and O images into the grid.

To declare a winner, would I be using an if else statement?

I'm just wondering how I can declare a winner.  I'm guessing this requires javascript.

Here's my code in jsfiddle, as well as what I have compiled below:

http://jsfiddle.net/VXQ7P/

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> <html>
> <head>
>
> <style type="text/css">
>
>   #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6, #div7, #div8, #div9 {
>       width: 80px;
>       height: 80px;
>       padding: 10px;
>       border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
>       float: left;
>   }
>   
> </style>
>
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     function allowDrop(ev) {
>         ev.preventDefault();
>     }
>
>     function drag(ev) {
>         ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
>         helper:clone;
>     }
>
>     function drop(ev) {
>         var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
>         ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
>         ev.preventDefault();
>     }
> </script>
>
> <title>JavaScript  Drag &amp; Drop Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <p>Drag the X and O images into the tic-tac-toe board:</p>
>     
>     <table>
>         <tr>
>             <td><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td><div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td><div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>             <td><div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
>
>     <img id="drag1" src="X.png" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75"/>
>     <img id="drag2" src="O.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75"/> 
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a number of approaches that might work, but typically, SO users won't solve a general problem like this for you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for an answer, but just a hint.  I'm not sure if my syntax is correct, but I'm trying to make if else statements

Answer (score 3):

In my opionion you are going a wron way there. You should use "onclick()" for every field and then change the innerhtml of the div to X or O. You might also want to google for "tic tac toe javascript". A lot of people did this before. Check out this one for example:  http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/ThPEH/
The way the winner is defined is very easy to understand and well explained there. ;)
Grabed from the site:

```
/*
 * To determine a win condition, each square is "tagged" from left
 * to right, top to bottom, with successive powers of 2.  Each cell
 * thus represents an individual bit in a 9-bit string, and a
 * player's squares at any given time can be represented as a
 * unique 9-bit value. A winner can thus be easily determined by
 * checking whether the player's current 9 bits have covered any
 * of the eight "three-in-a-row" combinations.
 *
 *     273                 84
 *        \               /
 *          1 |   2 |   4  = 7
 *       -----+-----+-----
 *          8 |  16 |  32  = 56
 *       -----+-----+-----
 *         64 | 128 | 256  = 448
 *       =================
 *         73   146   292
 *
 */
wins = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84],
```

**edit:**
You could store the state and the value of each TicTacToe-cell in an array. This way you can easily access them to determine if there is a winner.
http://pastebin.com/xDhBUfeS

Comment: Is it not possible to do this with the table tag using drag and drop?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. This would definitely also be possible with your drag&drop method.

Comment: How would I "tag" the table cells like in this example to declare a winner?

Comment: I would create an array in the beginning. Then just save the turns in it. If the userputs an X in the third cell go like: myArray[3] = "X"; when the user puts an O in the 6th cell go like: myArray[6] = "O"; After each turn you could now easily check all the cells and do the calculations mentioned above to determine the winner.

Comment: I put the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 ways by which a player can win. A straightforward way would be to test out each way using if-then-else. But first it would be nice to record the moves using two arrays, and numbering each square.

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop?

Loop through each row and column (and the 2 diagonals in the middle)